# How to get the words before and after a specific word from a textfile

Tags: string, python-3.x, tuples

I defined this function to find the keywords in a text file but, now i want to get a tuple containing the words before and after the key word in the file and i am not sure of how to do that

```
def findProperWords(paragraphs, excludedWords):
key = [] # an empty list
count = 0
for paragraph in paragraphs:  #calling of every paaragraph in the textfile
    count += 1 #counting each paragraph
    words = list(paragraph.split(' ')) 
           # spliting each paragraph into a list of words
    for keys in words: 
        if len(keys) > 0:
            if keys[0] == keys[0].upper(): 
                         #checking for words that start with capital letters
                if keys.lower() not in excludedWords: 
                     key.append(keys) # creating a list of the key words
                       index = paragraph.find(keys) 
                        # finding the position of each key word in the textile
```

Comment: Only a small tip: there is a built-in method for checking for upper case: `if keys[0].isupper():`. And `if len(keys) > 0:` can be written simply as `if keys:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this but please note that it would only find previous and next words within the paragraph. If you want it to find results in previous/next paragraphs consider creating one big lists of words (if memory limitations permits) or while iterating into a new paragraph update the previous one and when on last iteration of a paragraph save last word for later use.

```
def findProperWords(paragraphs, excludedWords):
key = [] # an empty list
count = 0
for paragraph in paragraphs:  #calling of every paaragraph in the textfile
    count += 1 #counting each paragraph
    words = list(paragraph.split(' ')) 
           # spliting each paragraph into a list of words
    for idx,keys in enumerate(words):
        if len(keys) > 0:
            if keys[0] == keys[0].upper(): 
                         #checking for words that start with capital letters
                if keys.lower() not in excludedWords: 
                     key.append(keys) # creating a list of the key words
                     index = paragraph.find(keys) 
                     # finding the position of each key word in the textile
                     if idx > 0:
                         word_before = words[idx-1]
                     if idx < len(words) -2:
                        word_after = words[idx+1]
```